# Points in circles that form a given geometric pattern

Tags: geometry

I am not a specialist in maths, so I thank you very much for any help you can give me.

Consider two circles C1, C2.

Q1: Find the points that are in the intersection of C1 and C2, this is easy !

Q2: Find two points p1 and p2, such that (p1 \in C1) and (p2 \in C2), and (distance(p1, p2)= D).
Is it possible to solve this problem ?

Now I want to generalize it to more than two circles and to arbitrary geometric predicates (or patterns)

Consider the circles C1, C2, ..., Cn

Q3: Find the points (p1 \in C1), (p2 \in C2), ... , (pn \in Cn) such that (Some_Geometric_Predicate(p1, ..., pn)= true).

Have you encountered this problem before ? are they any references that speak about such kind of problems ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass_and_straightedge_constructions


In particular, you'll find some key constructions that are impossible.

Comment: Q2 is the wrong level for MathOverflow and I'm unclear what exactly you mean by geometric predicates in Q3.  

Comment: @Austin: Thank you, will take a look
@Qiaochu: Q2 is mainly to introduce Q3.
Geometric predicate, for example, the points p1, ..., pn should a form a regular polygone, or any defined geometric pattern.

Comment: It is not clear what your "Find" means. Construct with ruler and compass? Find numerically? Determine for which configurations of circles a solution exists? These are very different questions, handled by different areas of mathematics.



Comment: Find in the sense that there is an exact algorithm that gives the exact points. For example for the intersection of two circles, I can have an algorithm that gives me the exact solution.

Comment: The solution can have coordinates like $\sqrt 2$ for simple integer-valued initial data (centers and radii). What do you mean when you say that an algorithm gives you this *exact* number? (The usual definition of the word "algorithm" is modelled after our familiar digital computers that don't have infinite-precision real numbers.)



Comment: Yes, square (2) is OK for me.
What I really want to do is the following:
I have 3 circles as input, and I have to find three points p1, p2 and p3 in these circles (a point in each circle) s.t. the angles of the triangle (p1, p2, p3) satisfy the following:
the angle at p1 is equal to a given a1.
... p2 ...a2.
... p3 ...q3.
Thank you.

Comment: I am a fool when it comes to geometry, but I think a solution to your general problem of finding 3 points forming a triangle with specified angles would imply that an arbitrary angle could be trisected, which is impossible.

Comment: @Austin: impossible with which tools?

Comment: I give a very specific example (my problem is more general than that):
I have circle C1 and two fixed points (p_a) and (p_b) in C1.
C2 and C3 are two circles intersecting with C1.
I need to find three points p1 and p2 and p3 s.t:
1. p1 is on C1, p2 on C2 and p3 on C3.
2. p_a, p1 and p2 are on the same line.
3. p_b, p1 and p3 are on the same line.
4. angle (p1, p2, p3) = X
5. angle (p2, p3, p1) = Y

Do you think that I can find a deterministic algorithm at least for this specific case ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permit me to reformulate a specific version of Q3 that
Ellipsissi posed in the comments:

> **P1**. Given three non-intersecting circles
>   $\{C_1,C_2,C_3\}$,
>   find all triples
>   $\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$ with $p_i \in C_i$
>   such that $\triangle p_1 p_2 p_3$ is
>   similar to a given triangle $T$.

This differs from the posed question in (a) the non-intersecting condition,
and (b) not demanding that a specific angle be realized at
a specific corner $p_i$.
The form above is analogous to this problem:

> **P2**. Given a plane curve $\gamma$,
>   find all triples
>   $\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$ of points on $\gamma$
>   such that $\triangle p_1 p_2 p_3$ is
>   similar to a given triangle $T$.

Much is known about P2, under various restrictions on $\gamma$.
For example, if $\gamma$ is a smooth Jordan curve,
then I believe it is almost completely understood now,
through recent work of
Benjamin Matschke, and of
Jason Cantarella, Elizabeth Denne, and John McCleary.
See especially Cantarella's fascinating [web pages on the topic](http://www.jasoncantarella.com/webpage/index.php?title=Square_Peg_problem#Results_on_Inscribed_Triangles).

So, here is a high-level plan for P1. Connect the three circles by thin
corridors to form a plane curve $\gamma$. 
Solve P2, and discard solutions with points on the corridors, or more than one point
on one $C_i$.
The efficacy of this plan depends on the degree to which
P2 is completely solved in its various guises.

**References**

1.
M. J. Nielsen. "Triangles inscribed in simple closed curves," 
*Geometriae Dedicata* **43**: 291-297 (1992).

2.
Benjamin Matschke.
"On the Square Peg Problem and some Relatives."
[arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.0186) (2009)

3.
Wikipedia article on the [Inscribed Square Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_square_problem), with triangles discussed under "Variants."

Answer (score 4):

I assume that "geometric predicate" is a logical formula involving known number of points, segments, etc, built from elementary predicates of Euclidean geometry ("this point lies on this line", "these two angles are equal" and the like) using boolean logic and quantifiers.

Then there is an algorithm that reads the text of this logical formula and coordinates and radii of the circles (assuming they are finite decimal numbers, or otherwise "exact") from its standard input, consumes extraordinary amount of memory and CPU cycles, but finally answers whether a solution (or many solutions) exist, and if yes, prints one of them with a given precision.

This works by translating the geometric question into a question about real numbers (coordinates) and using some algorithm implementing [Tarski's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TarskisTheorem.html).

Probably the program will run too long for all but very short formulas. Of course, there may be more efficient algorithms for some specific problems of this type. Or someone may invent better general algorithm in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Let me address just Q2. The set of points at distance $D$ from a point $p_1$ in $C_1$ form an annulus
centered on the center of $C_1$,
of outer radius $D+r_1$ and inner radius $\max \{ D-r_1, 0 \}$.  So you just intersect this annulus with $C_2$,
obtaining (in general) zero, one, or two arcs of $C_2$ 
for the locus of $p_2$ points that are distance $D$
from some point $p_1$.
**Edit**. See Sergei's comment below; I <strike>likely</strike> misinterpreted "p1 \in C1," which I read
as "in" rather than $\in$.

Comment: The inner radius should be $|D-r_1|$.

Comment: @Sergei: Hmmm. If, say, $r_1=10$ and $D=1$, 
then it seems one obtains a
disk of radius 11, rather than an annulus with inner radius $|1-10|=9$?  Ah, maybe we are interpreting $p_1 \in C_1$ differently.
I was interpreting it as $p_1$ _inside_ the circle, but I see that
may be a mistaken assumption. If it means $p_1$ _on_ the circle, then you are correct.

Comment: Yes, the meaning is that p1 is on the circle, not in the disk.
Thank you for your help.


Comment: @Ellipsissi: Apologies! So the radius is as per Sergei's correction.